# How do I get rid of the duplicates in this double mysql join?

Tags: php, mysql

I looked through other Q&A's and I didn't see my scenario.

My duplicates are weird.  Different logged in managers would get different amount of duplicates depending on how many users are under them.

```
SELECT user_groups.*, user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
FROM user_groups 
RIGHT JOIN user_table 
ON user_table.usergroup = user_groups.groupid 
RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
ON my_quotes.groupid = user_groups.groupid
```

Need to display results from my_quotes, but while also displaying other info from other tables.

A quote belongs to a user and also to the manager. when a manager creates a quote for a user, but there happens to be other users that the manager manages, the quotes table from the query above will show a quote for every user even though the quote belongs to just one user.

So say there are 2 users under the manager.  user 1 has a quote and user 2 has a quote. the quotes mysql table will only have 2 records so the html table should only display 2 records, but instead it displays 4 records. 2 for quote 1 and 2 for quote 2.

Now let's say another user is added under the manager.  the html table will then display 3 records for each quote.  it's weird.

The following doesn't work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_groups.*, user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
FROM user_groups 
RIGHT JOIN user_table 
ON user_table.usergroup = user_groups.groupid 
RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
ON my_quotes.groupid = user_groups.groupid
```

user_groups:

```
groupid, name, userid
```

user_table:

```
userid, username, email, usergroup, name, company, address, phone, manager, client
```

my_quotes:

```
id, userid, groupid, clientname, ponumber, date, postage, qty, price, total, approved
```

couple of the tables have too many fields to post. i just put the relevant ones to this problem.

one of the answers given helped, but there's still something wrong.  as you can see, there are 3 different queries depending if logged in user is admin, manager, or client.  the manager and client one displays correct records, and the admin one almost does, but there is a missing record for admin.

```
if($_SESSION['usergroup']==1) {

    $tableresult = mysql_query('

        SELECT user_groups.*, user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
        FROM user_groups 
        RIGHT JOIN user_table 
        ON user_table.usergroup = user_groups.groupid 
        RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
        ON my_quotes.userid = user_table.userid

    ') or die(mysql_error());

} else if($manager==1) {

    $tableresult = mysql_query('

        SELECT user_groups.*, user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
        FROM user_groups 
        RIGHT JOIN user_table 
        ON user_table.usergroup = user_groups.groupid 
        RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
        ON my_quotes.userid = user_table.userid 
        WHERE user_groups.userid='.$_SESSION['userid'].'

    ') or die(mysql_error());

} else {

    $tableresult = mysql_query('

        SELECT my_quotes.*, user_table.* 
        FROM my_quotes 
        INNER JOIN user_table 
        ON my_quotes.userid = user_table.userid 
        WHERE user_table.userid = '.$_SESSION['userid'].' 
        AND (approved = 1 OR approved = 2)

    ') or die(mysql_error());

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According To you example quotes are related with user's id, then you should `join`by user's id not by the group.

```
SELECT user_groups.*, user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
FROM user_groups 
RIGHT JOIN user_table 
ON user_table.usergroup = user_groups.groupid 
RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
ON my_quotes.userid = user_table.userid
```

New Answer For Admin: (Admin can see all the quotes)

```
SELECT user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
FROM user_table
RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
ON my_quotes.userid = user_table.userid //this will grab all the quotes
```

Comment: user_table doesn't have id, but that's a minor thing. i was going to say it doesn't work, but then i noticed you changed user_group to user_table. this seems to have worked. thanks. also i noticed you changed your answer, but i didn't feel like editing my reply here.

Comment: just noticed that a record missing in the list of quotes. not sure why. there are 3 queries. one for admins, one for managers, and one for users. users see their own. managers see all users under themselves. admins should see all quotes of all users under all managers. the manager one and user one seems right, but not the admin one. i will edit my question to see if you see something suspicious.

Comment: could you tell me which query for admin 1st, 2nd or 3rd??

Comment: Give me couple of minute to think

Comment: this query for admin gave this error: Not unique table/alias: 'user_table'

Comment: Do you have any user who don't have any usergroup??

Comment: no all users have a group. it's tricky because managers can create new groups for their users, but not sure if that matters, this new query seemed to have worked for admins. thanks a lot.

Comment: in other words, the managers are the admin's users, and the clients are the manager's users. or another way of saying it is, managers are the clients of admins, clients are the clients of managers, so that means clients are the admin's client's clients.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_groups.*, user_table.*, my_quotes.* 
FROM user_groups 
RIGHT JOIN user_table 
ON user_table.usergroup = user_groups.groupid 
RIGHT JOIN my_quotes 
ON my_quotes.groupid = user_groups.groupid
```

Use distinct or better coding.

Comment: please post table structures.